# Generate a path through 2d array Java

Tags: java, algorithm, path

Given a 2D array

```
|O|O|O|O|O|
|O|O|O|O|O|
|O|O|O|O|O|
|O|O|O|O|O|
|O|O|O|O|O|
```

I want to randomly generate a path through it. Below is the code that generates the path through the 2D array

```
    public void generatePath() {
    //choose random start position
    Random ran = new Random();
    int row = ran.nextInt(this.Graph.length);
    int col = ran.nextInt(this.Graph.length);

    // add step in the beginning
    this.Graph[row][col] = Node.S;
    Path initial = new Path(row, col);
    this.path.add(initial);

    // since the length can differ
    int rowLength = this.Graph.length - 1;
    int columnLength = this.Graph[0].length - 1;
    // at each iteration make an array of possible moves
    String r = "right";
    String l = "left";
    String up = "up";
    String down = "down";

    //A list of choices 
    int choice = 0;
    ArrayList<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();

    // total steps in path to generate
    int graphSize = Graph.length * Graph.length;
    int totalSs = graphSize*2;

    while (totalSs  > 0) {
        // add valid choices
        // check each move is within the size of the graph

        if (col < columnLength)
            choices.add(r);
        if (row < rowLength)
            choices.add(down);
        if (col > 0)
            choices.add(l);
        if (row > 0)
            choices.add(up);

       // choose a move randomly from the array
        choice = ran.nextInt(choices.size() - 1);
        String move = choices.get(choice);
        totalSs--;

        // perform move
        if (move.equalsIgnoreCase(r)) {
            this.Graph[row][col + 1] = Node.S;
            col += 1;

        }

        if (move.equalsIgnoreCase(l)) {
            this.Graph[row][col - 1] = Node.S;
            col -= 1;
        }
        if (move.equalsIgnoreCase(up)) {
            this.Graph[row - 1][col] = Node.S;
            row -= 1;
        }
        if (move.equalsIgnoreCase(down)) {
            this.Graph[row + 1][col] = Node.S;
            row += 1;
        }

        // add to path
        Path p = new Path(row, col);
        path.add(p);

        // clear array for next iteration
        choices.clear();
    }

}
```

Currently, have two problems with this code
Here is an example path that is generated
1)

```
 Path[0][1]
Path[1][1]
Path[1][0]
Path[1][1]
Path[1][0]
Path[1][1]
Path[1][0]
Path[1][1]
Path[1][0]
```

Notice how it generates a path that doesn't go back a row.. 
How would I change the code so that It can go from row [0]->[1] and have the ability to go back to row [0]

2) Many of steps are wasted as backtracks

Comment: What's your question, dude?

Comment: `ran.nextInt(choices.size() - 1);` doesn't do what you think it does. If you don't want to revisit previously visited cells (not the same as what's typically referred to as backtracking), keep track of visited cells and check whether a cell has been visited before going there - that's pretty common in path finding or generation.